# force sender to a type

Tags: windows-phone-7

I got the event sent from a button

```
private void myEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

send is a button, is it possible to get the button handler to access the parameter(such as tag) of the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to cast the sender parameter to it's native type in order for it to be treated as that type and therefore be able to access those properties

Something like this should be sufficient

`var button = (Button)sender`

You can then access the Button instance referenced by sender as a Button object

Answer (score 0):

cast the sender to a Button:

var button = sender as Button;